# Bash: any way to extract the first part of this string?

Tags: bash

I have a log with entries like

```
touch_file_1:23_1786880:/home/user/project
```

Is there any way to extract just the "touch_file_123" part into a variable? the number following it is an inode, and I want to get just the file name without the inode and the trailing path.

Even if the filename has underscores and numbers in it, I don't want to get rid of those, I just want to truncate the last occurrence of underscore followed by numbers.

Keep in mind my original filename can have colons in it as well, I want to keep all colons and underscores and numbers in my filename intact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
str='touch_file_1:11_2_3_1786880:/home/user/project'

echo "${str%_*}"
touch_file_1:11_2_3
```

`"${str%_*}"` will  truncate the last occurring underscore and everything that follows it.

Comment: thanks, will this work even if the filename has underscores followed by numbers?

Comment: unfortunately this will not work if the filename has underscores followed by numbers, it will strip away part of the file name.

I tried it with a file called touch_me_1_2_3 and it just returned touch_me , is there a way to make it return the original file name, even if it has underscores and digits in it?

Comment: The last and final occurrence of underscore followed by numbers is the part I want to truncate. There could be underscores and numbers before that last part, but I want to keep those intact as they may be part of the filename.

Comment: @stfudonny - the filename samples in your question did not include any numeric characters before the second underscore. This is why it's a great idea to include more extensive input when you create your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This would fail if the path also matches the pattern. In the general case, of course, there will always be the possibility of ambiguous cases where really you can't tell.

Comment: This will serve this requirement from OP **The last and final occurrence of underscore followed by numbers is the part I want to truncate**. Of course more examples will make it clear.

Comment: Sorry I updated my question to make it clearer in the example I provided. I'm trying to handle all cases, even if my filename has colons, or underscores followed by numbers in it.

In short I want to truncate the last occurring underscore and everything that follows it.

Comment: In that case `echo "${str%_*}"` will work for you, try it and let me know

Comment: Thank you! This did it, I think I've now covered all possible scenarios

Answer (score 1):

In Parameter Expansion, asterisks are non-greedy when used with shortest-pattern-match. If what you need is to remove "from the last underscore before a colon, to the end of the line", then expanding your glob should be sufficient:

```
$ a=( touch_file_1786880:/home/user/project foo_123_456_1786880:/tmp )
$ for f in "${a[@]}"; do echo "${f%_*:*}"; done
touch_file
foo_123_456
```

Alternately, if the condition is to remove "from the last underscore before a colon, **capturing only digits to the colon**, then any chars to the end of the line", you can do it with an extglob.

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ a=( touch_file_1786880:/home/user/project foo_123_456_1786880:/tmp )
$ for f in "${a[@]}"; do echo "${f%_+([0-9]):*}"; done
touch_file
foo_123_456
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash:

```
str='touch_file_1_2_3_1786880:/home/user/project'

[[ $str =~ (.*)_[0-9]*: ]] && printf '%s' ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
touch_file_1_2_3
```

The regex (no `shopt -s extglob` to set) will detect the string of numbers preceded by an underscore (_) and followed by a colon (:) and capture what is before that: the (.*).

This works reliably even for your updated requirements:

```
str='touch_file_1:11_2_3_1786880:/home/user/project'
[[ $str =~ (.*)_[0-9]*: ]] && printf '%s' ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
touch_file_1:11_2_3
```